# Position-sticky is not working with Bootstrap 4 elements

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm using the `.sticky-top` bootstrap class inside the child element of the column, which is inside a `.row` element. This way, the `.col` class element is taller than its child, and should theoretically allow the child to behave with `position: sticky;`. But, no matter what I try, the section doesn't stick to the top as intended.

Here is the [Codepen](https://codepen.io/abdulsalphan/pen/eYbVOaz).

The alphabet section on the right side is what I intend to make sticky.

The `.sticky-top` class works in the codepen. But, still not working on my project. Not sure how to reproduce the bug to display it here. Check my comment on Tom's answer to know more.

Comment: Please see [ask]. Links to code on other sites are not adequate. It's easy to create a functional demo here using the editor. Also, don't annotate edits. That's all visible in the [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77155667/revisions) anyway.